# Converting from decimal to binary without using bin() not printing

Tags: python, function, binary, decimal

I attempted to make an algorithm that prints a binary value of a number, but for some reason it quits instead of printing.

```
exponent = 4
binary = ""
def decToBin(userInput):
    global exponent, binary
    while (2**exponent) == 0:
        if (2**exponent) <= userInput:
            userInput = userInput - (2**exponent)
            binary = binary + "1"
        else:
            binary = binary + "0"
        exponent = exponent - 1
    return binary
print(decToBin(16))
```

Comment: If you just want to print the binary of an integer, why do not you use print("{0:b}".format(16)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `while (2**exponent) == 0` to `while exponent >= 0`, otherwise you never get inside or outside the while loop because `2**exponent` is always > 0, despite reducing `exponent` at each iteration. Also, there is no need for `global exponent, binary`; just put them inside the function.

Note that with your choice of `exponent = 4`, the `userInput` should be restricted to the range [0, 2**(exponent + 1) - 1] = [0, 31].

Here's an alternative algorithm (assuming that `userInput` is positive integer):

```
def decToBin(userInput):
    if userInput == 0:
        return '0'
    binary = ''   
    while userInput > 0:
        binary = str(userInput % 2) + binary
        userInput //= 2
    return binary
```

Answer (score -1):

Why should it do anything?

You start it with a `userInput` of 16 and an `exponent` of `4`. `2**4` == `16`. 
`16` is != `0` so your `while 2**exponent == 0` never triggers and never enters its block...

You need

```
while exponent > 0:
```

to get to your result. You are decreasing the exponent on each loop, so once it crosses 0 into negative you are done - not once 2**exponent does smth.

Comment: I don't know the downvoter's reasons, but the inverted test you suggest will result in an infinite loop (or rather, it'll stop when it hits floating-point underflow).